# Google Vision and Python script: ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Python 3.7, Windows 10 x86_64.
Trying to run a simple Google "Detect text in a local image" example as explained [on this page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr?hl=en), I always get this error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython'
```

Could someone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you try running this command ? ```sudo pip3 install -U grpcio```

Comment: This message indicates that the grpc artifact you have downloaded is not compatible with your architecture. Can you please share how exactly you installed your Python dependencies?

Comment: Thanks to Nestor and Richard. I finally used another machine with success, but will come back to the first one soon. Your suggestions will be useful.